# Rails: can http_basic_authenticate_with be done securely over HTTPS / SSL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, authentication, https

I'm having some trouble understanding how `http_basic_authenticate_with` works in Ruby on Rails. By default, I believe it sends the username and password to the server unencrypted via the HTTP protocol. I don't want to take that risk--I want them sent securely over HTTPS. If I have
`config.force_ssl = true`
in `config/environments/production.rb`, will authentication be secure, or is `http_basic_authenticate_with` somehow still an HTTP-only auth strategy? It doesn't seem to submit a visible request when I check requests in the console, so I'm not sure how to test this.

Comment: for starting point I suggest your read this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: @widjajayd, thanks, but I'll have an SSL certificate courtesy of Heroku. To be honest, I don't understand how much that accomplishes. Is it enough to guarantee everything sent from the client to the app is encrypted (despite the name of this method having http in it)?

Comment: To be as clear as possible, the method `http_basic_authenticate_with` causes a popup window to appear that prompts for a username and password. I don't see any request going through as a result of the user logging in through it